# how can i collect imgaes from template and save it to database in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want users to add blogs with images. So I have to collect images from them through the template and save them to the database. But it's just collect the name of the images.

views.py

```
def create_post(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title_id']
        catagory = request.POST['catagory_id']
        #author = request.POST['author_id']
        description = request.POST['description_id']
        notes = request.POST['notes_id']
        image = request.POST['image_id']
        author = request.user

        if not User.objects.filter(username=author).exists():
            messages.warning(request,'There is no account by this username. Please make sure you intput your username associated with your account')
            return redirect("/blog/create_blog/")
        blog_post = Applyforposting(title=title, catagory=catagory,content=description,author=author,notes=notes, images=image)
        blog_post.save()
        messages.success(request,'Your Submission is successful. Wait for approval')
    return render(request,'blog/create_post.html')'''
```

models.py

```
class Applyforposting(models.Model):

    approved = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    serial_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    catagory = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apply_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    notes= models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.serial_number) + '->' + self.author + '->' + str(self.apply_date) + 'approved>>>'+str(self.approved)
```

Comment: Do you have a `forms.py` file, how does your actucal html form looks like and do you set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in `settings.py`? Please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Share your forms.py code and check if images is in the project's media folder

- i suggest you to use https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor which will add a lot of dynamic and handle blogs with many options